# Incompatible and old pip packages.Many operations are not run stably in Flow Project

Tags: python, pip, sumo, flow-project

[image]Most of the pip packages in Requirements.txt are minus versions and they are incompatible with each other, so can you send the updated requirements.txt file or pip package versions.Many operations are not run stably for this reason.

```
gym==0.14.0
numpy==1.18.4
scipy==1.1.0
lxml==4.4.1
pyprind==2.11.2
nose2==0.8.0
six==1.11.0
path.py
joblib==0.10.3
python-dateutil==2.7.3
cached_property
pyglet==1.3.2
matplotlib==3.1.0
imutils==0.5.1
numpydoc
ray==0.8.0
opencv-python
dill
lz4
setproctitle
psutil
opencv-python
boto3==1.10.45
redis~=2.10.6
pandas==0.24.2
plotly==2.4.0
tabulate
tensorflow==1.15.2
awscli==1.16.309
torch==1.4.0
pytz
tensorboardX
```

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

my process normally is:

- Unpin patch verions (boto3==1.16 instead of 1.16.309), try to install, test your code.
- If this works, run pip freeze and update the requiremnts.txt file.
- If that doesn't work I'd unpin everything and try again.

don't forget to update pip before doing that, though